# text is not displaying in UIDatepicker

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uidatepicker

Date picker text is not display in Objective c. But when scrolling the date picker then the  date changing in logs

```
 UIDatePicker * datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake ( 0.0, 44.0, 0.0, 0.0)]; 
[datePicker setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
[Self.view addSubView:datePicker];
```

[image]

Comment: Showing code may be helpful...

Comment: change the text color or backgrpund color and check once

Comment: UIDatePicker * datePicker      = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake ( 0.0, 44.0, 0.0, 0.0)];
    [datePicker setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
 datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
[Self.view addSubView:datePicker];

Comment: change the width and height value of uidatePicker and text color as well

Comment: we did all scenarios.....but no result

Comment: look at the view debugger!

Comment: you just add date picker as subview  then from where  Done , Cancel button came , or you posted different image

Answer (score 1):

for example change the text color and try once

```
 [datePicker setValue:[UIColor redColor] forKey:@"textColor"];
```